# how to create a matlab vector inside a cell array using scipy's savemat

Tags: python, matlab, scipy

In python I am trying to use SciPy's savemat method to create a cell array that contains a vector of floats. I have tried the following: (have also tried lists and other types of np arrays)

```py
vector = np.array([2.3,66.7,22.0])
cell = np.array(vector,dtype=np.object)
io.savemat({'result':cell})
```

However this gives me the following output in MATLAB

```
result =

  1×3 cell array

    {[2.3000]}    {[66.7000]}    {[22]}
```

but what I need is the following {[2.3,66.7,22]}, nothing I have tried so far works.  Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Often I'll create the desired structure in Octave, write the `.mat`, and then look at what `loadmat` returns.  And follow that pattern in the reverse direction.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [25]: from scipy import io                                                   
In [26]: cell = np.array(np.array([1,2,3]), object)                             
In [27]: cell                                                                   
Out[27]: array([1, 2, 3], dtype=object)
In [28]: io.savemat('test.mat', {'result':cell})                                
In [29]: io.loadmat('test.mat')                                                 
Out[29]: 
{'__header__': b'MATLAB 5.0 MAT-file Platform: posix, Created on: Wed Oct  9 09:16:37 2019',
 '__version__': '1.0',
 '__globals__': [],
 'result': array([[array([[1]]), array([[2]]), array([[3]])]], dtype=object)}
```

So in both the original `cell` and the load, we have a 3 element array, with each element being a number, or a 2d array.

Let's make a single element array, with that element being an array itself:

```
In [30]: cell = np.empty((1,1),object)                                          
In [31]: cell                                                                   
Out[31]: array([[None]], dtype=object)
In [32]: cell[0,0] = np.array([1,2,3])                                          
In [33]: cell                                                                   
Out[33]: array([[array([1, 2, 3])]], dtype=object)
In [34]: io.savemat('test.mat', {'result':cell})                                
In [35]: io.loadmat('test.mat')                                                 
Out[35]: 
{'__header__': b'MATLAB 5.0 MAT-file Platform: posix, Created on: Wed Oct  9 09:18:55 2019',
 '__version__': '1.0',
 '__globals__': [],
 'result': array([[array([[1, 2, 3]])]], dtype=object)}
```